# Match string patterns including variables parts in Swift

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift, nsstring

I am trying match String patterns in Swift. In my case related to time,

## Example

**"in *1* week"**

**"in *4* weeks"**

I want to match the whole expression but return especially the number (Int) used between "in" and "week".

What's an efficient way to do this kind of string/pattern matching?

I did use e.g. **rangeOfString** for simple string matching before but I wonder how to tackle matching these more complex string patterns including its variable part.

Comment: Take a look at [regular expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html).  In this case the RE you need is "in ([0-9]+) weeks?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var pattern = "in\\s+(\\d+)\\s+weeks"
var error: NSError?
var regExp = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!

func getWeekCount(input: String) -> String? {
    let m = regExp.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, countElements(input)))
    print(m)

    if let mm = m as? [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        print(mm.count)

        if mm.count >= 1 {
            let range = m[0].rangeAtIndex(1)
            return NSString(string: input).substringWithRange(range)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("no match")
    }
    return nil
}
```